# how to activate current tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to activate the current tab even after refreshing the page. I used following code even though its not working I have written this in `index.html` by using Bootstrap and AngularJS

Can anyone solve this problem?

```
<ul role="navigation" class="nav nav-pills" id="MyTab">
  <li role="presentation" class="active" data-toggle="tab">
    <a href="#active">Active</a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation" data-toggle="tab">
    <a href="#list">list</a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation" data-toggle="tab">
    <a href="#add">Add</a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation" data-toggle="tab">
    <a href="#search">Search</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $("a[data-toggle='tab']").on("show.bs.tab", function(e) {
    localStorage.setItem("activeTab", $(e.target).attr("href"));
  });
  var activeTab = localStorage.getItem("activeTab");
  if(activeTab) {
    $("#myTab a[href='" + activeTab + "']").tab("show");
  }
});
</script>
```

I am trying this functionality using this JavaScript but it's not working please let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: You can use ng-class for adding the class active .

Comment: `it's not working` ... how about a little more information, like, what do you expect, what do you observe instead, are there any errors in the developer tools console

Comment: Why is this tagged on angularjs? And if you are using angularjs try avoiding jquery. Also are you using any router? Like Ui-router or ng-router?

Comment: yes i am using ngRoute...

Answer (score 0):

Get the active from localStorage and assign it to a scope variable .

```
$scope.activetab=localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
```

Set the active class based on the activetab value.

```
<li role="presentation" data-toggle="tab" ng-class="{active: activetab == 'list'}"><a href="#list">list</a></li>
<li role="presentation" data-toggle="tab" ng-class="{active: activetab == 'add'}"><a href="#add">add</a></li>
<li role="presentation" data-toggle="tab" ng-class="{active: activetab == 'search'}"><a href="#search">search</a></li>
```